# Is there a way to get shipping information and available shipping methods on the Product Detail Page in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

We implemented a new shipping method in our shop. This method isn't available for all Products. Now we want to create a notification on the product detail pages(pdp), where the shipping method is available. Is it possible to get the available shipping methods on the pdp?

It should look something like this:

```
if shippingMethods contains newShippingMethod
<div class="notifivcation">
```

Answer (score 0):

Shipping details have nothing to do with products from a Shopify perspective. If you have come up with a way to assign shipping methods to products, then that is excellent for you! Obviously, if you figured that out, then figuring out how to display shipping methods with products would be a lesser challenge.

Mostly, shipping methods are the domain of checkout in Shopify parlance. Only in checkout would shipping methods be available, and even then, if you wanted to show/hide them based on the product, you could really only hope to do that with Plus.

Unless you know more, and Shopify has really adopted a per product shipping methodology (feel free to post a link if true), you're not going to go anywhere with that unless you use Plus and script the checkout.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It wasn't me who figured out how to add the new shipping method for only a few products. It's a separate company, that has its own warehouse and offers delivery in under 2h for certain products in a certain area. They provided the Code for the shipping method and the snippet on the pdp. I'll have the next meeting with them tomorrow. I'll keep you updated, if you're interested. For now the workaround for us is that we add a tag for the products where the shipping method might be available and use it in a condition to show the snippet.

Comment: There are plenty of hack-jobs out there for Shopify. Decorating things is certainly one of the better ones. In the end, as long as the order makes sense, and is fulfilled correctly, it makes no difference how wild the front-end decorates things. I suppose that is all that this company is doing for you. They are responsible for order fulfillments via whatever code they inject in your store.